# How to read depth buffer in the lighting pass of deferred rendering without disabling depth test?

Tags: vulkan

So in the lighting pass of deferred rendering. I need the depth test for light volume but I don't need depth write. And I also need to know the depth value in the depth buffer. Both of them are read operations. So I thought it won't hurt anyone to attach the depth image as both InputAttachment and DepthStencilAttachment. But it turns out the InputAttachment only accept image of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL and DepthStencilAttachment don't like that layout.

Comment: "*it turns out the InputAttachment only accept image of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL*" That's not true. The standard defines several layouts that can be used with input attachments. For example, `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`. Now, the first usage of that attachment in a render pass can't use that attachment if you're clearing the attachment. You should provide your renderpass and image construction code so that we can see what isn't working.

Comment: @NicolBolas The code contains loads noises. I can't even extract  a meaningful snippet for this specific problem. But the validation complains: "Layout for input attachment is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL but can only be READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL or GENERAL.

Layout for depth attachment is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL but can only be  DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL, DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL or GENERAL."

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry, I get the layout wrong. should be `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` instead of `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL `. My code still not working but I guess that's somewhere else I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either a `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL`, or better yet `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` via the `VK_KHR_separate_depth_stencil_layouts` extension (resp. the Vulkan 1.2). This allows depth attachment to be used as an input attachment at the same time.

Comment: `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL` doesn't work for me but `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`  works. Haven't tried `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` yet but I guess it should work.